# Wp-login.php not signing in user

Tags: javascript, wordpress, fetch-api

```
let formData = [];
formData.push('log=' + encodeURIComponent(username) + '&pwd=' + encodeURIComponent(password) + '&wp-submit=Log+In&testcookie=1');
await fetch(window.location.origin + '/wp-login.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  body: formData[0],
}).then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
  window.location.reload();
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
});
```

The `fetch` returns `200` response whenever I post to `wp-login.php` so I am not sure what is wrong here. `Status Code` is also 302 whenever there is a successful login but mine is 200.

[image: Fetch response]

Comment: it returning 200 sounds like a wordpress bug, but you sure there isn't any CSRF token or captcha or something you need to supply as well?

Comment: This sounds like a database error, check to see if WordPress is setup properly to the domain you are using. You haven't moved hosts or changed domains recently have you?

Comment: @hanshenrik: I am working local.

Comment: @DustinSnider: No such thing was done.